# How to use ng-template in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-templates

I'm writing a client-side angular app and I have a question related to the way I can use angular's `ng-template`.

So, I have this `navbar`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" >
        <div class="container-fluid">              
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!--<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>-->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Events <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Create Event</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-include="getTemplate()">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Ok, in the last `<ul>` tag I use `ng-include="getTemplate()"`, where getTemplate is this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var getTemplate = function () {
                return "notauth";
            }
        })
    </script>
```

Basically, this will return the same template, but I just want this to work before I add more logic to it.

**"notauth" template is:**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="notauth">
        <li><a ui-sref="signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </script>
```

Note that this is inside my index.html page, because I want my navbar to be the same for all views, but change its template according to user state: if user is logged in use auth template, otherwise use notauth template.

**Problem is that this doesn't work and I can't figure out what the problem is.**

Comment: Tell me if there are any console errors?

Comment: @CharanCherry nothing in console

Comment: What is your auth template?

Comment: @Sai is not defined yet, but I'm not using it now. I will probably remove SignUp and Login and add something like Profile and something else.

Comment: Set a variable like `loggedin`. If true render `auth`, else render `noauth`.

Comment: Thing is, if I just add those `<li>` tags without trying to use ng-template, everything works perfect.

Comment: @Sai, you didn't get my question.

Comment: Isn't the ng-template working?

Comment: @Sai ng-template is not working. That is my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the function using $scope as follows:

```
  $scope.getTemplate = function () {
       return "notauth" ;
       console.log("notauth")
  }
```

Then you can call like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-include="getTemplate()">
```

This works correctly.

Comment: I don't have a controller defined for my index.html page. I just use ng-app, and each view that will be used later has it's own controller.

Comment: Define this in main controller ie. in index.html controller.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your function doesn't work is because you define your function in a function (that is automatically called by jQuery) and is thus only available in the scope of that function.

But even if you were to add the `getTemplate()` to the global (window) scope, it would still not work as Angular looks for it on the current `$scope` object.

So the only way you can make this work:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-include="getTemplate()">
```

Is if you somehow get `getTemplate()` onto the current `$scope` or the `$rootScope`. This can be accomplished by for instance the following code:

```
angular.module('myApplication', [])
    .run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.getTemplate = function() {
            return 'notauth';
        };
    }]);
```

Do note however that while something like this may work, you're much better of creating a component for this functionality which can then have an injectable controller that can actually perform smart logic.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-include="'notauth'"` works like this, not `ng-include="notauth"`

So, try to do something like that.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    angular.module('app', []).
    controller('MainC', function($scope){
    $scope.call = function(){
      return 'notauth';
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, If I hard code ng-include="'notauth'" it works, but when i use getTemplate(), this function doesn't get called.

Comment: Where should I define this function?

Comment: Define it in controller

Comment: And what if I don't have a controller for index.html page?

Comment: Define a controller

Comment: Ok, let me try!

Comment: Copy this code and keep `ng-controller="MainC"` in that particular `<ul>` element